Forcing HTTP error 421 on all HTTP2 requests
I have Apache 2.4 setup on my server serving webpages with the HTTP 1.1 protocol. The system is currently not ready to handle HTTP2 (please dont ask why).
When reviewing server logs, I saw a few of these requests in my access_log
PRI * HTTP/2.0  400  18  -  -

So I want to prevent my server from being worn down with such requests from google.
I look here on google: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/googlebot and it states I should issue HTTP error code 421 to solve my problem. My server produces error code 400, not 421.
Rather than try to figure out how to make an apache module, is there some setting I can use in httpd.conf or some premade module I can use to make all HTTP2 requests issue error 421 so my logs don't get excessively hammered?

Google does state that to opt-out from crawling over HTTP/2, you can instruct the server to respond with a 421 HTTP status code.
You can achieve it by using this in Apache:
<If "%{HTTP2} == 'on'">
  Header set Status "HTTP/1.1 421 Misdirected Request"
</If>

Warning: Be aware that search engines may decide not to index a URL that returns a 421 Misdirected Request response status. Additionally, previously indexed URLs that now return this status code may be removed from search results. Please be extra careful when implementing this solution.

I'm not sure if that would work because wouldn't I need the apache HTTP2 module installed to detect the value of the HTTP2 flag?

As per the manual https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html HTTP2 is an Apache request related variable. It only evaluates if the connection is requesting it.

Is there a way to implement such a solution without risking the removal of web pages from search results?
